# Blender 3.2 -EEVEEE How to SubSurface Scatter all the way through a thin cube?

Tags: shader-nodes

EEVEEE How to SubSurface Scatter all the way through a thin cube? In this case it's the default Cube made very thin.
if the shader Subsurface is set to a higher value like 1000, it still never goes through to the front. The Shader is from this tutorial
[Blender Subsurface Scattering Workflow Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzubP4UU2nk)

[image: default scene and spotlight]

Comment: Enable subsurface translucency in properties/material/settings.

Comment: Do you mean "transmission"? I do not find the " translucency in properties"

Comment: No.  I'll give you a pic in  a real answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable subsurface translucency in properties/material/settings:

[image]

Comment: SOLVED - cheers